# swift - paginate tableview data from API

Tags: ios, json, swift, api, pagination

Please advice how can I paginate my tableview. I get data from the CocktailDB API and parse JSON with Decodable. There are categories and drinks from these categories.
I want to firstly load 10 drinks and then load more when I scroll to the bottom of the page.
I considered using willDisplay method by tableview.
Thank you in advance!

My code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    struct OneCategory {
            let name : String
            var drinks : [Drink]
        }
    
    var drinks = [Drink]()
    var categories = [OneCategory]()
    
    var selectedCategoriesArr: [String] = []
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        loadAllCategories()
        
    }
    
    func loadAllCategories() {
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/list.php?c=list")
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
            
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
                return
            }
            
            do {
                let result = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as! [String:Any]
                let categoryNames = (result["drinks"] as! [[String:String]]).map{$0["strCategory"]!}
                let group = DispatchGroup()
                
                for category in categoryNames {
                    let categoryURLString = "https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/filter.php?c=\(category)"
                        .addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!
                    let categoryURL = URL(string: categoryURLString)!
                    
                    group.enter()
                    let categoryTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: categoryURL) { (categoryData, _, categoryError) in
                        
                        defer {
                            group.leave()
                        }
                        
                        if let categoryError = categoryError {
                            print(categoryError)
                            return
                        }
                        
                        do {
                            let drinks = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: categoryData!).drinks
                            self.categories.append(OneCategory(name: category, drinks: drinks))
                        } catch {
                            print(error)
                        }
                    }
                    categoryTask.resume()
                }
                
                group.notify(queue: .main) {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
                
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return categories.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return categories[section].name
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return categories[section].drinks.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "drinkCell") as! DrinkCell
        
        let category = categories[indexPath.section]
        let drink = category.drinks[indexPath.row]
        cell.drinkName.text = drink.strDrink
        
        let url = drink.strDrinkThumb
        cell.drinkImage.downloaded(from: url)
        
        return cell
    }
}
```

Models:

```
struct Response:Decodable {
    var drinks: [Drink]
}

struct Drink:Decodable {
    var strDrink: String
    var strDrinkThumb: String
}


struct Categories:Decodable {
    var drinks: [Category]
}

struct Category:Decodable {
    var strCategory: String
}
```

Comment: I didnt see a paging support from the API you used. Ussually it will have a page parameter to support paging

Comment: You can try use this API that support paging if you want https://docs.thecatapi.com/pagination